# Given a `RealType`, find an unsigend integral type `SizeType` which is able to store any value of `SizeType`

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits

Given a floating-point type `RealType`, how can I find an unsigned integral type `SizeType` such that `RealType` is able to store any value of `SizeType`? At first glance, it seems like the `<type_trait>` library doesn't contain a suitable template.

Comment: Are you looking for the _largest_ `SizeType` that satisfies this?  An IEEE `float` can represent any integer that is 23 bits or fewer.  And IEEE `double` can represent any integer that is 52 bits or fewer.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

Comment: As the question is phrased, the solution is easy: let `SizeType` be `uint_least8_t` (the smallest unsigned integer type -- if that has a value that `RealType` cannot represent, then no unsigned integral type will satisfy the condition). Nothing fancy required, so I suspect some key intent is missing from or altered in the question.

Comment: From the title: *"find an unsigend integral type `SizeType` which is able to store any value of `SizeType`"* -- the last part is a tautology, so pick any unsigned integral type. Or perhaps, `RealType` is supposed to be mentioned somewhere?

Comment: When you say "any value of", you mean "every possible value of", right?

Answer (score 2):

`<type_traits>` wouldn't have a template, as this is a property of the numeric representation of a floating-point number. That's handled in `<limits>`.

`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` is the [number of digits that can be "represented without change" in the floating-point type `T`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits). For floating-point types, this is the number of digits in the mantissa.

However, these digits are in the base `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix`, which does not strictly speaking *have* to be 2. I mean, it *will* be if `numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` is true, which is almost every implementation of floating point types. But just be aware that it doesn't *have* to be.

So given this, all you need to do is look at a bunch of unsigned integer types from smallest to largest until you find the first where `numeric_limits<RealType>::digits >= numeric_limits<UIntType>::digits`. Start from `unsigned char` and work your way up to `unsigned long long int`.

```
template<typename UIntType, typename FloatType>
constexpr static bool can_hold_all_values = std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::digits >= std::numeric_limits<UIntType>::digits;

template<typename FloatType>
constexpr auto find_uint_type()
{
  if constexpr(can_hold_all_values<unsigned long long, FloatType>)
    return (unsigned long long)0;
  else if constexpr(can_hold_all_values<unsigned long, FloatType>)
    return (unsigned long)0;
  else if constexpr(can_hold_all_values<unsigned int, FloatType>)
    return (unsigned int)0;
  else if constexpr(can_hold_all_values<unsigned short, FloatType>)
    return (unsigned short)0;
  else if constexpr(can_hold_all_values<unsigned char, FloatType>)
    return (unsigned char)0;

  //Fail at compile-time.
  throw int{};
}

template<typename FloatType>
using uint_type_t = decltype(find_uint_type<FloatType>());
```

Comment: @david-fong: You could use `std::conditional_t` here, but I see no reason why one might do so. A large conditional like that would be even harder to read. It would also require a lot of template instantiation that is unnecessary.

Comment: This appears to find a `SizeType` such that `SizeType` is able to store (the integer part of) any value of `RealType`. The question asks the reverse, a `SizeType` such that `RealType` is able to store any value of `SizeType`.